# Why does my script stop executing commands after calling an .EXE?

Tags: python, executable

Here is the relevant code from a Python script where a few commands are executed to copy an executable file and then execute it:

```
exe_file_path = os.getcwd() + r'\name_of_executable.exe'
temp_loc = os.environ['temp']

subprocess.Popen(r'copy %s %s' % (exe_file_path, temp_loc), shell=True)
exe_file_path = os.environ['temp'] + r'\name_of_executable.exe'
subprocess.Popen(r'start %s' % (exe_file_path), shell=True)
subprocess.Popen(r'del %s' % (exe_file_path), shell=True)
```

Currently, `name_of_executable.exe` only prints out text and then calls `system("pause")`.

After the pause is executed, I push `enter` and I would assume the executable would close and the Python script would continue, but the last line of Python doesn't execute.

Is this because I'm using the TEMP folder? (I'm executing from a command prompt running as administrator. How do I get the script to work?

Comment: Note that you can also use the `shutil` package to handle file copy/move/delete operations.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All programs will be immediately started one after another. Call [communicate](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate)  on each Popen object to wait for program termination.

Additionally, your use of format strings is unnecessarily dangerous. `['copy', exe_file_path, temp_loc]` automatically escapes any strange characters in `exe_file_path` and `temp_loc` (and is easier to read).

By the way, Python has very good functions for copying and deleting files in [shutil](http://docs.python.org/library/shutil.html) and [os](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html); there is no need to call shell programs for that.

And instead of concatenating strings to determine `exe_file_path`, you should use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) (although this is not that important, since your program seems locked to Windows).

Comment: I notice that they are indeed all being started one after another, however, adding `.communicate()` to each line didn't fix the problem. Do I need to put the returning output and error into a variable for that "effect" to happen? Editing the format strings now.. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the Python tips. Obviously a novice at this language.

Comment: @josmh Notice that start returns immediately after it has spawned the new process. Just remove the start (the full ine would be `subprocess.Popen([exe_file_path]).communicate()` and use shutil/os functions for the two other invocations.